# MYDOMAIN\MSSQLUser. xp_delete_file() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.' [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22049). The step failed

Tags: sql-server

> MYDOMAIN\MSSQLUser. xp_delete_file() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.' [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22049). The step failed.

I am getting error while I tried to execute job for below script

```
DECLARE @DELETE_DATE NVARCHAR(50),
        @DELETE_DATE_TIME DATETIME;

SET @DELETE_DATE_TIME = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
SET @DELETE_DATE = (SELECT ( REPLACE( CONVERT( NVARCHAR, @DELETE_DATE_TIME, 111), '/', '-') + 'T' + CONVERT( NVARCHAR, @DELETE_DATE_TIME, 108)))

EXECUTE xp_delete_file 0, N'location', N'BAK', @DELETE_DATE, 1
```

When I run this script it works fine. But when I tried to run it on job it displays above error.

Comment: `xp_delete_file()` ->acces filesystem , when you run it you probably have all priviliges, but SQL Server Agent Account not.

Comment: any idea on it how to make this job run successfuly

Comment: Check the job history to find out under which accont the step was executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. In the script below I removed last value 1 and it worked finely.

```
DECLARE @DELETE_DATE NVARCHAR(50),
        @DELETE_DATE_TIME DATETIME;

SET @DELETE_DATE_TIME = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
SET @DELETE_DATE = (SELECT ( REPLACE( CONVERT( NVARCHAR, @DELETE_DATE_TIME, 
111), '/', '-') + 'T' + CONVERT( NVARCHAR, @DELETE_DATE_TIME, 108)))

EXECUTE xp_delete_file 0, N'location', N'BAK', @DELETE_DATE
```